# Proof that solutions of the ODE $y''+q(x)y=0$ have at least one zero

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

The solutions of the differential equation $$y''+q(x)y=0,$$ where $q$ is positive and bounded, have infinitely many zeros. The proof for this either uses the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem, or is fairly complex. [(Link)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3812904/prove-that-if-ywxy-0-then-y-has-infinitely-many-zeroes)

However, if we only want to show that $y$ has (at least) *one* zero, is there a more elementary proof for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y$ is negative everywhere then we know that $y''$ is positive everywhere,
This means that $y'$ is strictly increasing and hence cannot be $0$ everywhere. Pick $x_0$ such that $y'(x_0) \ne 0$.

If $y'(x_0)>0$ then for $x>x_0$
$$y(x) = y(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^x y'(t)dt  \ge y(x_0) + (x-x_0)y'(x_0)$$
So if $x$ is large enough then $y(x)>0$, a contradiction.

If $y'(x_0)<0$ then for $x<x_0$

$$y(x) = y(x_0) - \int_{x}^{x_0} y'(t)dt  \ge y(x_0) - (x_0-x)y'(x_0)$$

So if $x$ is small enough then $y(x)>0$, a contradiction.

Hence $y$ cannot be negative everywhere.

You can derive a similar contradiction for everywhere positive $y$.